# Handling multiple MySql queries (Deleting and Copy)

Tags: mysql, sql

Good morning.
I have a table on MySQL DataBase.
In this table there are 5 robots that can write like 10 record each per hour.
Every 3 month a script that I have created, make a copy of the table and then delete all the table entries (In this way I can keep the IDs in a certain order).

My question is.
That are two different statement:

```
CREATE TABLE omologationResult_{date} AS SELECT * FROM omologationResult
DELETE FROM omologationResult
```

if the script is going to copy the table at point 0, and a record will be added from the robots, there's no problem, because the SQL statement starts from the lowest ID 'till the end. But if the script is going to `delete` the table and the robot is writing in it. What will happen? I lose the last robot record?

And if it's true. What can I do to make a copy of the table and then remove only the data that I've copied?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is not a safe operation because it's not atomic. It's quite possible for another thread to insert values into that table in between your CREATE .. SELECT and the DELETE. One option you have is to use a multi table [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html)

```
CREATE TABLE omologationResult_{date} AS SELECT * FROM omologationResult;
DELETE omologationResult FROM omologationResult 
INNER JOIN omologationResult_{date} ON omologationResult_{date}.id = omologationResult.id
```

Will ensure that only items that exist in both tables have been deleted from omologationResult

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to have been of help